# WindowsAzure.ServiceBus version with no Access Control Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, authentication, azureservicebus

Currently my application uses [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) 2.8.2 package and I can check on Fiddler that traffic to o https://{your-namespace}.accesscontrol.windows.net is present. In my understanding this [will stop working in early November](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/7-month-retirement-notice-access-control-service/).

I would like to know what is the minimum version of the Service Bus client library I can use where some other approach other them Access Control is used. Could not find anything on documentation about this.

My application targets .NET 4.0 and I am considering upgrading the framework version or using the Service Bus via REST.

Thank you,

Igor.

Answer (score 0):

All the versions after the version 2.8.2 of WindowsAzure.ServiceBus requires .Net Framework 4.5 or above. I am using WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 5.0.0 with .Net Framework 4.6.1 and find this combo to be stable and reliable.

Comment: I know about the .NET Framework 4.5 requirement for versions after 2.8.2, thank you. But my question is more in the sense of what is the minimum version of this library, if any, there was the change to not use Access Control anymore, so I could use it without having problems after November.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is retiring ACS authorization soon. To avoid downtime of the namespaces, you should migrate to SAS authorization.

To migrate and handle namespaces created under ACS, check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/05/18/acs-migration-guide/)